# Operations in a matrix with (i,j) values with no for or while loops

Tags: r, matrix

I need to write a function in R that receives as input an integer number n>1, and generates an output matrix P, where P_{i,j} = min (i,j) for(i,j)=1,...,n. This function must not have `for` nor `while` loops.

So far I have tried with the following code.

```
mat <- function(n){
  m <- matrix(0,nrow = n,ncol = n)
  if(row(m) >= col(m)){
    col(m)
  }
  else{
    row(m)
  }
}
```

I know that with the if conditions, row(m) and col(m) I should be capable to look over the matrix, however, I don't know how to set that for that conditions I can have the min of row(m) and col(m) in the (i,j) position. I know I won't achieve the latter with the conditions I have above, but so far is the closest I've been.

An example is the following.
If n=3, then the result should be:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    2    2
[3,]    1    2    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pmin`, `row` and `col`

```
f1 <- function(n = 3) {
  mat <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)
  pmin(row(mat), col(mat))
}


f1()
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    2    2
#[3,]    1    2    3
```

---

Or use `outer` and `pmin` which is more effiecient

```
f2 <- function(n = 3) {
  idx <- sequence(n)
  outer(idx, idx, pmin)
}
```

**benchmark**

```
library(microbenchmark)
n <- 10000
b <- microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(n),
  f2 = f2(n),
  times = 10
)

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(b)
```

[image]

```
b
#Unit: seconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   f1 5.554471 5.908210 5.924173 5.950610 5.996274 6.058502    10   b
#   f2 1.272793 1.298099 1.354428 1.309208 1.464950 1.495362    10  a
```